# Class in javascript just show the lastest state when process

Tags: javascript

i have the following code:

```
solve(maze){
        let animateMaze = [];
        function resolveMaze(maze){
            let currentCell = maze.getNextUnsolveCell();
            //already solved maze
            if(currentCell===undefined) {
                return true;
            }
            let availableValues = maze.getAvailableValues(currentCell);
            for(let value of availableValues){
                maze.setValueForCell(currentCell,value);
                console.log(maze); //always show the final maze, not the current maze
                animateMaze.push(maze);
                if(resolveMaze(maze)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            maze.setValueForCell(currentCell,0);

            return false;
        }

        if(resolveMaze(maze)){
            return animateMaze;
        }
        else
        {
            return undefined;
        }

    }
```

i have an object maze in that code. what i tried to do is pushing the state of the object maze to an array. I will use this array to show the process step of the function. But i dont know why in each step, when i console log the maze, the value of maze is always the final state ( after processed is done). And array animateMaze is contain array of the same maze.
Does anyone has any solution for this?

Comment: I can see no `class`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `maze` variable is a reference to one object. In `js` any time you pass a reference to a function, it will copy the reference and this reference will still point out to the **same** object. And so every time you call `resolveMaze` function it uses the **same** `maze` over and over. The solution is to copy `maze` variable before calling a `resolveMaze` function so it takes new `maze` every time.

> So how do I copy `maze` variable?

It depends on what `maze` variable represents, because it can either a class instance, an 
object, it can have nested structures and so on. So it's up to you find proper way to copy it.

Hope it was clear and helpful :)

Comment: thank you for your explanation. the maze object is a class instance. I gonna find a way to clone it ;)